# In which form elements there are no changes in HTML 5, they are same as like they were in HTML 4.01?

Tags: html, xhtml

In which form elements there are no changes in HTML 5, they are as it is as they were in HTML 4.01 <del>but still valid</del>?

Answer (score 3):

Nothing relating to form controls is valid in HTML 4.x and not valid in HTML 5.

Comment: I mean which elements are still we will use and there is no change in those. I think one is `<select>` element.

Comment: @Jitendra Vyas: There are new attributes in HTML5 that could apply to any form element, so therefore everything has changed in that sense. What particularly are you concerned about?

Answer (score 1):

All of them are changed, because there are [new attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/#new-attributes) for every form element.  As David says you can use many form elements in a backwards compatible way, but why is that important to you?